# Фильтрация массива с данными

Tags: javascript

```js
let arrDate = ['06-13', '06-17'];

let arr = [
  ['06-10', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 34567, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.5, 4234, 4234, 4311, 3245, 422, 23, 34532, 77685, 4234, 4234, 4311, 3245, 422, 23],
  ['06-11', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 55435, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.4, 4345, 4553, 431, 5678, 44, 42, 13467, 53256, 4345, 4553, 431, 5678, 44, 42],
  ['06-12', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 43, 55600, 0.3, 3642, 3642, 443, 433, 224, 55, 14134, 52466, 3642, 3642, 443, 433, 224, 55],
  ['06-13', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
  ['06-14', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
  ['06-15', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
  ['06-16', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
  ['06-17', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23],
  ['06-18', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
  ['06-19', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
  ['06-20', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
  ['06-21', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
  ['06-22', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23]
];


arr.filter((item) => {
  if (item[0] !== arrDate[0]) {
    arr.shift()
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Вот у меня есть такие 2 массива:

- `arrDate` это массив с датами `от` и `до`
- `arr` это массив с данными, где первый элемент это дата

Необходимо из второго массива сделать выборку по датам `от` и `до`

И пишу такой код что, если у меня не совпадает дата от и дата из данных, то я удаляю первый массив, то есть который идет до совпадения с числом

Но вот отрабатывает он неправильно, выводит совсем не то что надо:

```
  ['06-17', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23],
  ['06-18', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
  ['06-19', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
  ['06-20', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
  ['06-21', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
  ['06-22', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23]
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
  ['06-13', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
  ['06-14', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
  ['06-15', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
  ['06-16', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
  ['06-17', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23],
```

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос `то я удаляю первый массив, то есть который идет до совпадения с числом` - ничего не понятно, первый массив это `arrDate`  по вашим же словам, как вы его удаляете, а проще напишите простыми словами что хотите получить в результате, можно даже с примером

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Мне нужно получить данные входящие  в диапазон дат, Например : От даты 06-12 до даты 06-16 и удалить все что находится перед датой 06-12 и после даты 06-16

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо

Comment: добавь в вопрос результат, который хочешь получить для массива из вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтр в данном случае не очень удобное решение, тем более модификации массива делать в нем не стоит - для этого есть `reduce`. Все что нужно сделать в данном случае так как массив упорядочен, найти начало и конец выборки, это делается через `findIndex`  метод массива возвращающий индекс элемента совпадающего с условием. После чего методом `slice` мы можем безболезненно вырезать нашу выборку в новый массив.

```js
let arrDate = ['06-13', '06-17'];

let arr = [
['06-10', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 34567, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.5, 4234, 4234, 4311, 3245, 422, 23, 34532, 77685, 4234, 4234, 4311, 3245, 422, 23],
['06-11', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 55435, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.4, 4345, 4553, 431, 5678, 44, 42, 13467, 53256, 4345, 4553, 431, 5678, 44, 42],
['06-12', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 43, 55600, 0.3, 3642, 3642, 443, 433, 224, 55, 14134, 52466, 3642, 3642, 443, 433, 224, 55],
['06-13', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
['06-14', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
['06-15', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
['06-16', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
['06-17', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23],
['06-18', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
['06-19', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
['06-20', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
['06-21', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
['06-22', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23]
];


const start =  arr.findIndex(e => e[0] === arrDate[0])
const end =  arr.findIndex(e => e[0] === arrDate[1])
const result = arr.slice(start, end + 1)
console.log(result)
```

выведет:

```
  ['06-13', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 32454, 24300, 23, 24300, 0.4, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64, 14141, 35243, 5232, 55, 6644, 555, 323, 64],
  ['06-14', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 56463, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.67, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532, 32532, 46357, 6363, 3523, 3422, 244, 133, 532],
  ['06-15', 876, 43500, 2.013793103448276, 77532, 43500, 12, 43500, 0.96, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42, 35253, 76544, 5425, 5532, 4266, 345, 145, 42],
  ['06-16', 234, 55600, 0.420863309352518, 54352, 55600, 3, 55600, 0.56, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53, 52352, 64865, 6452, 555, 785, 422, 423, 53],
  ['06-17', 345, 24300, 1.4197530864197532, 21453, 24300, 54, 24300, 0.45, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23, 14134, 56436, 5425, 1344, 3344, 332, 144, 23],
```

Comment: Спасибо большое